# What visa type should I apply to attend a 10 day summer school in Italy?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, italy

I am from India and selected for a fully funded summer schoool. I applied under tourist visa, it was suggested by the institute itself and was rejected on the grounds that justification of the purpose of the visit and conditions of the stay were not provided. I am reapplying, I want to be careful to not get refused. After 10 day summer school, I intend to stay for 4 more days to tour Italy. I am employed as a researcher at a research institute.
What type of visa is appropriate? What documents should I furnish? What should I be very careful about?

Comment: I am also from West Bengal and I have an experience with schengen visa. I applied for short stay student visa. I attached the award letter. But the 1st visa application was rejected due to some unknown reason (probably I didn't include the NOC from my institution), however I applied again with almost same documents with additional NOC letter. Then I got the Visa. I hope you will get the visa for the 2nd time, make sure you attached all documents and also mention the lodging address there has been booked for you

Comment: Please read the [Help](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help) file, and know that this is not a discussion forum. Instead, this stack seeks questions that have declarative answers, not opinions. You've asked three questions, and should limit yourself to one at a time. Using the "edit" button above what you've written, limit what you ask to one question.

Comment: @Traveller Well...one of them.

Comment: Is this summer school relevant to your research? Did you apply stating that this was related to your work, or that you were doing this recreationally? What did you put as "main purpose of visit"?